# Replace string on loop

Tags: c#, string

I'm working on a razor page where I need to drop a series of custom fields from a variable-attribute tables. My purpose is to replace a specific pairing of symbols ('{}') with an htmlstring. To simplify however lets say i wanted to replace it with an incremental number.

This is pseudo-code for what i'm looking for.

```
string s = "This sample will count: {}, {}, {}."
int i = 0;
while(*string not finished*)//?
{ 
   i ++;
   s.Replace("{}", i);  
}
```

Output:

```
"This sample will count 1, 2, 3."
```

Is this something I need to use regex on? Any other thoughts?

**EDIT**

I should clarify: I am not aware of how many '{}'s until run time. The numbers may be throwing people off, I'm liking going to do something more akin to:

```
 s.replace("{}", stringArray[i]);
```

Comment: Strings are immutable in `.NET`. Can only transform from one string to another.

Comment: @ja72 Yes I know, but even if I swapped it into StringBuilder, which is what replace likely does behind the scenes, my question remains valid i think. The objective isn't to count, the objective it to replace each sub-string fitting the pattern with a **different** substring. In my actual instance the source is probably going to be strings from an array or list. If I did s.replace(1) Then the output would be "This sample will count 1, 1, 1"

Comment: So, you're trying to replicate `string.Format()`, but without numbers inside the braces?

Comment: There's an overload of string.Format which takes a param (you could pass your list direcrly as an array), if you could get your input with numbers in the braces it would be perfect.

Comment: @Magus That's not an unfair assessment. In my instance programmers don't get to write the strings. Users do in real time, string s is coming from a database. I was not aware of string.format(str, array). Given Pierre's comment, all I really need is to add the numbers in, which ironically makes my dummy example not so dummy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression [match evaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) as follows:

```
var re = new Regex(@"\{\}");

string s = "This sample will count: {}, {}, {}.";

string[] replacementStrings = new string[]{"r1", "r2", "r3"};

int i = 0;

string n = re.Replace(s, m => 
    {
        return replacementStrings[i++];
    }); 

Console.WriteLine(n); // outputs: This sample will count: r1, r2, r3.
```

Comment: Thanks, though I won't have the option to hard code the number of replacement strings.

Comment: Please elaborate.  The above solution is based on your EDIT regarding s.replace("{}", stringArray[i]);

Comment: Your code takes into account there are specifically three bracket pairs. Otherwise it functions quite well.

Comment: @Seth: This solution will work regardless of the value of replacementStrings. That just needs to be a parameter. It definitely does not constrain it to only 3.

Answer (score 3):

A simple sample using Split to tokenise your input string;

```
string s = "This sample will count: {}, {}, {}.";
string[] tokens = s.Split(new[] { "{}"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

int counter = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++ )
{
    sb.Append(tokens[i]);
    if (i < tokens.Length - 1)
        sb.Append(counter++);
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Solves your posted example, but I imagine your real requirement is going to be subtly more complicated.

Comment: This leaves out the last token. (in this case, the `.` at the end)

Comment: Corrected (but not tested)

Answer (score 1):

If performance is important to you, traverse the string manually and write its contents to a `StringBuilder` (to prevent tons of string instance creations while concatenating and replacing strings) and then find and replace instances of the `{}`. `string.IndexOf` would be good to use for this. Once you're done, cache the result and output the string builder via `StringBuilder.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with plain old string manupulation:

```
string s = "This sample will count: {}, {}, {}.";
string[] stringArray = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };
int i = 0, c = s.IndexOf("{}");
while(c >= 0)
{
    s = s.Remove(c) + stringArray[i++] + s.Substring(c + 2);  
    c = s.IndexOf("{}");
}
// s == "This sample will count: 1, 2, 3."
```

Or using regular expressions:

```
string s = "This sample will count: {}, {}, {}.";
string[] stringArray = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };
int i = 0;
s = Regex.Replace(s, "{}", m => stringArray[i++]);
// s == "This sample will count: 1, 2, 3."
```

Or using Linq:

```
string s = "This sample will count: {}, {}, {}.";
string[] stringArray = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };
s = String.Join("", s.Split(new[]{ "{}" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                     .Select((x, i) => i < stringArray.Length ? x + stringArray[i] : x));
// s == "This sample will count: 1, 2, 3."
```

Comment: These examples will have poor performance due to the number of strings being created.

Comment: @DavidHaney Poor performance as compared to what? Do you have any proof actually that this "loss" of performance will be meaningful?

Comment: Yes, the strings will be instantiated, and thus need to be garbage collected. You'll create a lot more Gen 0 or 1, possibly 2 GC events, which will slow down your application. `StringBuilder` exists SOLELY to circumvent the overhead of creating string instances as by-products of operations that repeatedly manipulate them.

Comment: MSDN mentions performance issues, unfortunately without much detail, here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx

Comment: Either way this never deserved the downvote, as it's still a correct answer, if not the best.

Comment: Regex.Replace(string, MatchEvaluator) method uses StringBuilder internally to build the resulting string.